# Using a Styled Map

Tags: android, json, resources, maps

We want to use the JSON from Google Documentation on
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling in our mobile application, and wondered if it is totally free to use or are there any charges/fees after X amount of usages?
To be specific we would like to use the **loadRawResourceStyle**

Thanks!
Yariv

Answer (score 0):

I use this for some years now. Completely free. All you need is basic Google Maps API key.